# URL Error : Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

Tags: swift

I am using WinguGallery pods. I want to view the photos in the link I took from MSSQL with wingugallerry. I can successfully extract data. But "let asset = ImageAsset (url: url!)
I'm getting "Data 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in line "I'm successfully retrieving data from the database. But probably when defining the variable in the url part. The data I took is the string variable.

```
import UIKit
import WinguGallery

class GelisimController: UIViewController {
func fillWithGifs() {

        let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
  client.connect("ddd", username: "ddd", password: "ddd", database: "ddd") { success in
             client.execute("SELECT ddd FROM ddd", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                                                    var gifsa: [String] = []
                             for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {

                               for row in table {

                                    for (_, value) in row {

                                    if let intVal = value as? String {
                                gifsa.append(String(intVal))
                               var returnArray: [ImageAsset?] = [ImageAsset]()
                                            for item in gifsa {
                                            let url = URL(string: item)
                                            let asset = ImageAsset(url: url!) //error line
                                           returnArray.append(asset)
                                                                }
                                        self.winguGalleryView.assets = returnArray
                                        print("returnArray", gifsa)
                                                                }} }}
                                        client.disconnect()
                                          })}
       }
```

Comment: It looks like `item` is invalid URL, so `URL(string: item)` did not created. Check what is in `item`.

Comment: When I print the item, it shows that the data is properly assigned. @Asperi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your for loop like this

```
for item in gifsa {
   guard let url = URL(string : item) else {continue}
   //Rest of the code here
}
```

Try not to force unwrap if you're unsure of the values. :)